# __stack_chk_fail when executing copy_process() in _do_fork()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fork, intel, qemu

I'm trying to do an experimental project about linux kernel(4.4.52) on x86_64, and one requirement of which is that whenever the control flow leaves specific function, the Write Protection bit in CR0 register would always be enabled. Generally speaking, it is like(the idea comes from [nested kernel](https://github.com/nestedkernel/PerspicuOS), but that is not very relevant to my question):

```
DISABLE_CR0.WP_BIT
original_func()
ENABLE_CR0.WP_BIT
```

By doing that, the whole kernel would be executing with CR0.WP enabled. I have replaced the original [native_set_pte](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64.h#L53) function and [native_write_cr3](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/special_insns.h#L49) function with the format above, and now the kernel crashes when booting.

Here is the log(that's its original log, although the sequence seems weird):

```
[    1.403888] IP: [<ffff8800351ebbb0>] 0xffff8800351ebbb0
[    1.403891] PGD 2876067 PUD 2877067 PMD 3500e063 PTE 80000000351eb163
[    1.403892] Oops: 0011 [#2] SMP
[    1.403898] Modules linked in: crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd psmouse pata_acpi floppy
[    1.403901] CPU: 0 PID: 143 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G      D         4.4.52v1+ #2
[    1.403902] Hardware name: Fedora Project OpenStack Nova, BIOS 0.5.1 01/01/2011
[    1.403903] task: ffff8800351c0e00 ti: ffff8800351e8000 task.ti: ffff8800351e8000
[    1.403905] RIP: 0010:[<ffff8800351ebbb0>]  [<ffff8800351ebbb0>] 0xffff8800351ebbb0
[    1.403906] RSP: 0018:ffff8800351ebba8  EFLAGS: 00211086
[    1.403906] RAX: 000000000000000e RBX: ffff8800351ebcf8 RCX: 000000000000000e
[    1.403907] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000201092 RDI: 0000000000201092
[    1.403908] RBP: 0000000000000003 R08: ffffffff82778d60 R09: ffff8800351ebb40
[    1.403909] R10: 0000000000000030 R11: ffffc00000000fff R12: ffff8800351c0e00
[    1.403909] R13: 0000000000000010 R14: 0000000000201046 R15: ffffffffffffffff
[    1.403911] FS:  00007f1f021e38c0(0000) GS:ffff88003fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    1.403912] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    1.403912] CR2: ffff8800351ebbb0 CR3: 00000000351cd000 CR4: 00000000001406f0
[    1.403916] Stack:
[    1.403918]  ffffffff810b62ae ffff8800351ebbc0 000000000000006c 0000000000000000
[    1.403920]  ffff8800351ebbd8 ffffffff810b62ae ffffffff8111ce51 00000000000364a4
[    1.403921]  ffffffff82783168 000000000000005c 000000000000000c ffffffff820583b0
[    1.403922] Call Trace:
[    1.403928]  [<ffffffff810b62ae>] ? kvm_sched_clock_read+0x1e/0x30
[    1.403930]  [<ffffffff810b62ae>] ? kvm_sched_clock_read+0x1e/0x30
[    1.403933]  [<ffffffff8111ce51>] ? __raw_callee_save___pv_queued_spin_unlock+0x11/0x20
[    1.403935]  [<ffffffff8111c49e>] ? down_trylock+0x2e/0x40
[    1.403937]  [<ffffffff81129959>] ? console_trylock+0x19/0x60
[    1.403938]  [<ffffffff8112af2e>] ? vprintk_emit+0x29e/0x530
[    1.403945]  [<ffffffff8115fe8e>] ? crash_kexec+0x7e/0x140
[    1.403953]  [<ffffffff81440ae5>] ? find_next_bit+0x15/0x20
[    1.403955]  [<ffffffff814390bb>] ? __const_udelay+0x2b/0x30
[    1.403958]  [<ffffffff810a2a0c>] ? native_stop_other_cpus+0x8c/0x170
[    1.403965]  [<ffffffff811dde8f>] ? panic+0xeb/0x215
[    1.403968]  [<ffffffff810d12a7>] ? copy_process+0x727/0x1b20
[    1.403970]  [<ffffffff810d32f9>] ? __stack_chk_fail+0x19/0x20
[    1.403972]  [<ffffffff810d12a7>] ? copy_process+0x727/0x1b20
[    1.403974]  [<ffffffff810d2808>] ? _do_fork+0x78/0x360
[    1.403975]  [<ffffffff810d2b99>] ? SyS_clone+0x19/0x20
[    1.403986]  [<ffffffff818694f2>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[    1.404004] Code: 00 00 00 86 10 21 00 00 00 00 00 a8 bb 1e 35 00 88 ff ff 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 b0 bb 1e 35 00 88 ff ff ae 62 0b 81 ff ff ff ff <c0> bb 1e 35 00 88 ff ff 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    1.404005] RIP  [<ffff8800351ebbb0>] 0xffff8800351ebbb0
[    1.404006]  RSP <ffff8800351ebba8>
[    1.404006] CR2: ffff8800351ebbb0
[    1.404008] ---[ end trace b62acacf75e0c54f ]---
[    1.406415] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    1.456105] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: ffffffff810d12a7
[    1.456105]
```

I guess the problem is that something at `copy_process` causes an overflow, maybe it writes to some read-only memory? But **`CR0.WP` bit should only affects the supervisor mode** according to intel's document, so does that mean kernel is running in supervisor mode when executing `copy_process`?

I tried to disassemble the kernel, and got really upset about all those countless assembly instructions... So I decide to find it out with qemu. However, the kernel did **NOT** crash in qemu!! The command I use is that

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1G -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd arch/x86/boot/linux4.4.52-rootfs.img -hda vdisk.img --append "root=/dev/sda rw console=ttyS0" -nographic
```

I used to think that `_do_fork` is independent of specific devices and filesystems(correct me if I'm wrong), so what causes the kernel to crash at my VPS should make it crash at qemu as well, which it didn't.

Has anyone come across the same issue? I really need some help now.

P.S. I do this at my VPS, ubuntu 16.04.2, but I think this is not the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that QEMU is not fully architecture accurate model, and QEMU do not provide full support of all architecture referenced features, because QEMU aim is emulation speed, not accuracy, and then it only provide some workable architecture profile to run OS.

Some features QEMU do precise and correct like paging and segmentation, but many are not : there are some troubles with CPUID, syscall, many instructions do not generate #GP, #SS, #PF, floating point errors, some instructions are not implemented (AVX, AVX2, FMA) and so on.

You should use one of x86 golden models to catch such tricky cases: try to use [Bochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochs), or one of provided by Intel itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it turned out to be the problem of pivoting the stack, which caused some unknown problems. Since this question is relevant to programming and has nothing to do with the linux kernel itself, I think I should close it. But thanks for sharing some knowledge about QEMU.